# Install FTP server with support for virtual users

Tags: server, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I'm trying to install an FTP server on Ubuntu 11.04. I've installed vsftpd, but I had no success in getting it to work with virtual users. I want to be able to have give fake users and direct them to some directory.

Answer (score 6):

This chapter will show you how to convert your Linux box into an FTP server using the default Very Secure FTP Daemon **([VSFTPD](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_%3a_Ch15_%3a_Linux_FTP_Server_Setup#Introduction))**

Comment: wow its a book, not a cheapter! there is no 1-2-3 steps for doing it?

Comment: do you have maybe a video tutorial?